# Loop start from 2 instead of 1 in python continue statement

Tags: python, while-loop, continue

I am learning continue statement in python while loop. If I run a following code, the output shows from 2 instead of 1.

```
    a = 1
    while a <= 8:
        a += 1
        if a == 5:
            continue
        print(a)
```

Comment: You initialise `a` to 1, then in the loop you add 1 to it before printing. That means you print 2.

Comment: Could you clarify what your question is? You initialized a=1, then you did a+=1 so a =2 then. If you move a+=1 to after your print statement then it will print a=1 first.

Comment: @KunalShah thanks for reply. Can you share code, please? The output starts from 2 (2,3,4,6,7,8), but I want from 1 (1,2,3,4,6,7,8)

Answer (score 0):

You go through the body of the while condition once, 1 + 1 = 2 then print(2)

Answer (score 0):

a += 1 is coming before the print statement, that's why it's printing 2.
Your a == 5 condition is also not executing because a is 2.

you can elaborate your question more if you haven't got the answer yet.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is below and I have annotated it with the value of a

```
a = 1 #### a is 1 here obviously ####
while a <= 8:
    a += 1 #### a is incremented by 1, so the value of a is 2 here ####
    if a == 5:
        continue
    print(a) #### the value of a is 2 when you print ####
```

To have the counter start from 1 instead there are many options depending on what you are trying to accomplish. Here are a few choices:

```
a = 0
while a < 8:
    a += 1
    if a == 5:
        continue
    print(a)
```

Or

```
a = 1
while a <= 8:
    if a != 5:
        print(a)
    a += 1
```

Comment: If I use the second code, continue statement does not work. Output stops at 4 (1,2,3,4)

Comment: @Imtango30 sorry that was my bad, I have edited my answer